# How to convert IEnumerable<object> to IEnumerable<...MVC.Rendering.SelectListItem> asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to display a dropdownlist on my page with a list of titles.  My object is

```
public class Title
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I have a view model that contains the line -

```
public IEnumerable<Title> Titles { get; }
```

And in my page I have -

```
<select  asp-for="Person.TitleId" asp-items="@Model.Titles"/>
```

But I get the error:

> Cannot implicity convert type 'IEnumerable<Models.Title> to IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem>

How do you convert?

Thanks

Comment: Found a solution.  .Select(i => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = i.Description.ToString(),
                Value = i.Id.ToString()
            });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer -

```
 var listOFTitles = _titleRepository.Titles.Select(i => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = i.Description.ToString(),
                Value = i.Id.ToString()
            });
```

Comment: Yes, you should use selectListItem to use this form of dropdownlist, and you can set your answer as an answer if it helps